# How to find the number of shifts in a sorted list from an unsorted list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, count

I have an unsorted list `lis=[4,2,1,3]` using the sort function I get the value as `lis=[1,2,3,4]` now the numbers 1,3,4 have been shifted making the shift count to 3 shifts. How do I count the number of shifts in Python?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
sum(i!=j for i,j in zip(lis,sorted(lis)))
# 3
```